# Loading modules from JSON with details

Tags: php, json

I have a function that is supposed to load a module from a json file. Here's the function:

```
$json = file_get_contents("modules.json");
$modules =json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    include('include/scripts/' . $module);
}
```

And this is the JSON:

```
["gallery.class.php", "blog.class.php", "members.class.php"]
```

This function works, but I want it to have more details, like weather it's enabled or not, and a description, etc

Comment: @Darren I was just about to do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be setting up your `json` as an array **`[]`** or objects **`{}`**.

That'd look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "gallery",
        "description": "DESCRIPTION",
        "link": "gallery.class.php"
    },
    {
        "name": "Blog",
        "description": "DESCRIPTION",
        "link": "blog.class.php"
    },
    {
        "name": "Members",
        "description": "DESCRIPTION",
        "link": "members.class.php"
    }
]
```

And in your php code you'd just loop through the json data as items

```
$json = file_get_contents("modules.json");
$modules =json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    include('include/scripts/' . $module['link']);
}
```